# How to set Property value using Reflection?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, generic-programming, system.reflection

I try to build a Generic Method which take class and set value using reflection and return a class type.

```
protected static T GetSecureModel<T>(T model)
        {
            T secureModel = default(T);

            foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
            {

                    if (string.CompareOrdinal(property.PropertyType.FullName, "System.String") == 0)
                    {
                        property.SetValue(property.Name, property.GetValue(model, null).ToString(), null);
                    }
             }

              return secureModel;
}
```

How to return a Class after set value ?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I solve it. Check below code, It may be helpful for someone.

```
   protected static T GetSecureModel<T>(T model)
        {
            bool secureData = false;

            T secureModel = default(T);

            foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.GetValue(model, null) != null && property.GetValue(model, null).ToString() != _blankGuid && property.GetValue(model, null).ToString() != _zero)
                {
                    if (string.CompareOrdinal(property.PropertyType.FullName, _uniqueIdentifier) == 0)
                    {
                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, new Guid(Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(property.GetValue(model, null).ToString())), null);
                    }
                    else if (string.CompareOrdinal(property.PropertyType.FullName, _numeric) == 0)
                    {
                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, int.Parse(Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(property.GetValue(model, null).ToString())), null);
                    }
                    else if (string.CompareOrdinal(property.PropertyType.FullName, _string) == 0)
                    {
                        model.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(property.GetValue(model, null).ToString()), null);
                    }

                    secureData = true;
                }

            }

            if (secureData)
            {
                secureModel = model;
            }

            return secureModel;
        }
```