# Typed Data Row - insert data based on the column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, dataset, datarow

I have a table where I am storing data based on certain criteria. Both tables are typed tables.
tblShipper has around 10 columns and tblParsedData has 3 columns(ID, FieldName, FieldValue)

I created a row from tblShipper, to add FieldValue for each column. However, as we know typed row will show column names.

I cant find a way to do something like the code below or something better.

```
MyDataset.tblShipperRow _newRow = _tblShipper.NewtblShipperRow();
foreach(tblParsedDataRow _row in _parsedDataForShipper.Rows)
    _newRow[_row.FieldName] = _row.FieldValue;
_tblShipper.Rows.Add(_newRow);
```

**More details:**
tblParsingParams stores parameters, we use these parameters to read data from file, parse the data that we read and store it in key/value format in tblParsedData.

tblParsedData has fields like: key, value, tablename (table for which this data is), columnname.

On run time, I am created a dataset for tblShipper or any other table, then I am loading data from tblParsedData into data table. Now I need to insert data from tblParsedData data table into tblShipper Dataset. Bind this dataset to a gridview, so that user can view and verify/edit the data, and later save it into database (tblShipper).

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388544/insert-data-into-typed-row-on-the-fly-based-on-column-name

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way to do so. I used reflection to do this, use reflection to load all properties of typed row and compare it with the column name. If it matches, set the value using reflection. Easy!

```
MyDataset.tblShipperRow _newRow = _tblShipper.NewtblShipperRow();
foreach(tblParsedDataRow _row in _parsedDataForShipper.Rows)
{    
      foreach (var property in _newRow.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
            if (_row.FieldName == property.Name)
            {
                 property.SetValue(_newRow, _row.FieldValue, null);
                 break;
            }
      }
}
```

Used a bit from the below post

[How to set Property value using Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813743/how-to-set-property-value-using-reflection)